# Reflexivity and dual space

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces, reflexive-space

We know that $(\ell^2,\|.\|_2)$ is a reflexive space. Thus $(\ell^2,\|.\|)$ is reflexive for any norm $\|.\|$ on $\ell^2$ equivalent to $\|.\|_2$. Thus $(\ell^2,\|.\|)^{**}=(\ell^2,\|.\|)$. My question is what can we say about $(\ell^2,\|.\|)^{*}$? Is it $(\ell^2,\|.\|^{\prime})$ for some norm $\|.\|^{\prime}$ on $\ell^2$ or it can be some other space. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Well, $\ell^2$ is a Hilbert space, and Hilbert spaces are self-dual.

Comment: But we don't know that $(\ell^2,\|.\|)$ is a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the norm in $\ell^2$ by an equivalent norm, you will not change the continuous linear functionals. Any linear functional which is bounded w.r.t. $\|\cdot\|_2$ will also be bounded w.r.t. $\|\cdot\|$ and vice versa. Hence, the dual space is the same but it is endowed with a different norm.